# osclass - latest premium items in a XML/PHP/HTML file in html format

Tags: php, opencart, osclass

## Requirement:

I have to write a script that calls latest premium items on the home page of OpenCart from OsClass.

### My directory structure:

OpenCart is installed on the root of website, and OsClass is installed inside classifieds folder in the root.

```
../public_html/ (OpenCart is installed here)
../public_html/classifieds (OsClass is installed here)
```

#### Website URL's:

```
www.example.com (OpenCart based main website)
www.example.com/classifieds (OsClass based Classifieds)
```

I basically need help from any senior, in finalizing the perfect method to get above requirement fulfilled.

Comment: By *finalising* I understand You have the functioning function body and You need some help with it. So, why is it not yet included in the question?

Comment: @shadyyx No buddy, by _Finalizing_ i mean, I am just starting work on this task and wants an Expert opinion about the perfect method of doing this task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include this on the homepage of Opencart

```
<?php
require_once 'classifieds/oc-load.php';
$items = osc_query_item('premium=1');
// DISPLAY HERE $items AS YOU WANT
// print_r($items);
?>
```

Take a look at the function osc_query_item, you may want to modify the params to do display other items
https://github.com/conejoninja/Osclass/blob/master/oc-includes/osclass/helpers/hItems.php#L1353

Comment: This is not working, it says:

`Notice: Constant DB_PASSWORD already defined in ***\config.php on line 15
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class Session in ***\oc-includes\osclass\core\Session.php on line 23`